# Декораторы в JS

Tags: javascript

Добрый день, подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом, в примере ниже, х передается в возвращаемую функцией cachingDecorator внутреннюю функцию? Из какого замыкания? Спасибо!

```js
function slow(x) {
  return x;
}

function cachingDecorator(func) {
  let cache = new Map();

  return function(x) { // как попадает сюда x ?
    if (cache.has(x)) { 
      return cache.get(x); 
    }

    let result = func(x); 

    cache.set(x, result);
    return result;
  };
}

slow = cachingDecorator(slow);

alert( slow(1) );
```

Comment: Из аргумента задекорированной функции slow. Непонятно, что именно вам непонятно.

Comment: Наверное, вас смутило, что в функции `slow` название параметра тоже `x`.